# Microsoft Graph Api returning ADOperationFailedTransient error when posting a new calendar event

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Our system integrates with Microsoft Graph Api to add calendar events to our User's outlook calendar

We started seeing a new type of error returned from the API. The User's calendar had been syncing fine up until today.

```
{
  "error":
  {
    "code":"ADOperationFailedTransient",
    "message":"The Active Directory operation failed with transient error.",
    "innerError": {
      "requestId":"cfb964dd-4fe3-4324-9f61-258113668601",
      "date":"2020-11-06T00:20:39"
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what this error means?

Comment: Yeah, its nothing to do with Microsoft Graph API, rather i believe AAD is failing here!!

Comment: This seems to have gone away on it's own

Comment: Yes @Sean this i was suspecting as well; sounds like some technical glitch... Glad that its working now for you!!

Answer (score 0):

We have seen the same sort of errors coming in as of a few hours ago for accounts that were previously syncing.

```
Unavailable endpoint for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ADOperationFailedTransient",
    "message": "The Active Directory operation failed with transient error.",
    "innerError": {
      "requestId": "f89f2781-8c6c-4407-a685-97a56fbabe76",
      "date": "2020-11-06T00:49:24"
    }
  }
}
```

```
Unavailable endpoint for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorADUnavailable",
    "message": "Active Directory is unavailable. Try again later."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sounds like some technical glitch due to that you may have noticed the issue... Glad that its working now..!! In such scenario, i would recommend you to test with POSTMAN or Graph Explorer and see if you can repro the issue or not. This will help you to isolate the issue outside of your code/application.